# Cannot modify multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have two arrays.
First one ($dcel) looks like this:

```
Array(
[1] => Array
    (
        [V1] => 5
        [V2] => 2
        [F1] => 4
        [F2] => 1
        [P1] => 7
        [P2] => 4
    )
etc..
```

Second one ($PctOldNew) looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [old] => 1
        [new] => 3
    )
etc..
```

I'm trying to find the 'old' values (which are the initial) in the first array. Here's my code:

```
foreach ($dcel as $latura) {
    for($i = 0; $i <= $nrPct; $i++){
        if($PctOldNew[$i]['old'] == $latura[V1]){
            $latura[V1] = $PctOldNew[$i]['new'];
        }
    }
}
```

If I output the $PctOldNew inside if statment, the output it's the correct answer, but if i try to modify $latura[V1] the $dcel remains untouched.
I've tried with reference, keys... but nothing works and i can't see what's wrong.

Comment: so `foreach($del as &$latura {` didn't work?

Comment: because that works for me, using your code (except I had to change the value of [V1] in your initial array to '1' since there's nothing to actually match in your posted example). sidenote, you should wrap your associative indexes in quotes you did it for the 'old' and 'new' but it should be done for `$latura['V1'] as well.

Comment: well if that didn't work, then there's something else going on somewhere else in other code, beyond that. IOW what I posted is proper, and the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

**edit: adding a 2nd array element to $dcel to show how it works**

```
<?php
$dcel = Array(
'1' => Array
    (
        'V1' => 1, // <-- note that i changed this value from your original '5' to '1' so that your condition will actually match something, since this example data set doesn't actually have something to match
        'V2' => 2,
        'F1' => 4,
        'F2' => 1,
        'P1' => 7,
        'P2' => 4
    )
'2' => Array
    (
        'V1' => 5,
        'V2' => 2,
        'F1' => 4,
        'F2' => 1,
        'P1' => 7,
        'P2' => 4
    )

);
$PctOldNew = Array(
'0' => Array
    (
        'old' => 1,
        'new' => 3
    )
);

foreach ($dcel as &$latura) { // <-- reference on &$latura
    for($i = 0; $i <= $nrPct; $i++){
        if($PctOldNew[$i]['old'] == $latura['V1']){
            $latura['V1'] = $PctOldNew[$i]['new'];
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($dcel);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [V1] => 3
            [V2] => 2
            [F1] => 4
            [F2] => 1
            [P1] => 7
            [P2] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [V1] => 5
            [V2] => 2
            [F1] => 4
            [F2] => 1
            [P1] => 7
            [P2] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: for me this doesn't work. it just copies the first found value to the rest of $latura[V1]

Comment: @TaseButcaru okay that doesn't even make sense. What do you mean by "the rest of `$latura[V1]` ? Post example output of what you mean

Comment: i was referring to the next array in $dcel

Comment: @TaseButcaru umm, no it doesn't. See my edit. I added a 2nd array element to $dcel, so there's 1 that will match and one that won't. Look at updated output. The first V1 which matches gets replaced, while the 2nd one doesn't get replaced.  Copy and paste this code by itself in its own script, you will see for yourself it works. Therefore as I previously said, if this doesn't work for you, then you have code elsewhere that's affecting things.

Comment: I agree that this should work, but it just doesn't. Probably there's a problem somewhere else. This is the entire code http://pastebin.com/g8kdCg8j - you can copy the raw code and run it here http://writecodeonline.com/php/. You'll have 2 tables - first is the initial one with original V1 / V2 cols. and the second table contains the V1 col changed and as you can see there is just one value (2).

Comment: i made it work this way by inserting a "break" before ending the if statement AND "unset($latura)" after foreach loop. In my project i run a few times other foreach loops for $dcel and probably that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@CrayonViolent it didn't work, i tried so many times.
I was playing right now with the code and it seems that like this it's working:

```
foreach ($dcel as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $val) {
        for($i = 0; $i <= $nrPct; $i++){
            if($PctOldNew[$i]['old'] == $value[V1])
                $new = $PctOldNew[$i]['new'];
        }
        $val = $new;
    }
    $dcel[$key][V1] = $val;
}
```

...but i don't know why.

Comment: In your foreach loop, `$key` and `$value` are temporary variables used for the `foreach` iteration. They aren't permanent variables that reference the actual `$dcel` array.  So in your first attempt, `$latura` is the equivalent of `$value` and is a temp var. Which is why you put the `&` prefix to make php reference the `$dcel` array itself.  So this method here works because instead of doing like `$value[V1]` which is a temp var, you are assigning to `$dcel` directly with `$dcel[$key][V1]`

Answer (score 0):

Another weird way is to use `array_walk`

```
array_walk(&$dcel, function($latura){
  for($i = 0; $i <= $nrPct; $i++){
      if($PctOldNew[$i]['old'] == $latura[V1]){
          $latura[V1] = $PctOldNew[$i]['new'];
      }
  } 
});
```

Or `array_map`

```
$dcel = array_map(function($latura){
  for($i = 0; $i <= $nrPct; $i++){
      if($PctOldNew[$i]['old'] == $latura[V1]){
          $latura[V1] = $PctOldNew[$i]['new'];
      }
  } 
  return $latura;
}, $dcel);
```

(Not sure why `array_walk` and `array_map` have reversed parameter position)

Updated with the real reason and 2 more possible solutions

The reason you can't modify `$latura` is because you are using `for...each` loop which will pass `$latura` by-value rather than by-reference. Based on this reason, you have 2 more solutions,

- Use `for $dcel as $key => $latura` then you can change `$dcel[$key]`
- Use `for $dcel as &$latura` then you can change the item directly

Comment: i cannot use array_walk (deprecated) - probably diff php versions and array_map, again, doesn't modify the $dcel array. the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Weird, http://fi2.php.net/array_walk I don't see any deprecated mentioned there. As for `array_map`, yes it doesn't modify the item, but it does construct a new array with modified items (not sure if it fits your case)

Comment: This is what i get "Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in...".
Anyway, I got it working with the code below. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I see the comment mentioning that deprecated warning now. `array_map` should do what you need. The reason you can't modify `$latura` is because you are using `for...each` loop which will pass `$latura` by-value rather than by-reference. There is another way, though, that is to use `for $dcel as $key => $latura` then you can change `$dcel[$key]`

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way in your case would be using `array_map()`  function
Like this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$replacements = array(
    array('old'=>1, 'new'=>11),
    array('old'=>3, 'new'=>33),
);

$array = array_map(function($element){ 
    global $replacements;
    foreach($replacements as $r) if($r['old']==$element) return $r['new'];
    return $element;
}, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array ( 11, 2, 33, 4, 5 )
```